# Scrollview scrolling is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have added a UIscrollview in my detail view. I just need to make that scrollview on same position whenever user come back to top or bottom

Now currently it is showing 64 spacing on top and if I am changing it's top content position then it is scrolling in negative direction of the view may be it's -64 position. 
I want it's scrolls properly in both direction from 0,0 position.

Can any one suggest me what am I doing wrong.

Here is the simulator screenshot 
[image: Simulator]

Storyboard
[image: Storyboard constraints]

Comment: Try in viewDidLoad self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: Thanks for reply Jon but I have tried this too.

Comment: Try changing your navigation bar to to Opaque Navigation Bar by changing the Top Bar value on your view controller.  Using a translucent bar sometimes causes that issue.  If changing the bar to Opaque Navigation Bar fixes your issue then we can provide you with a solution.